# Can't commit to Github: error: git-seekret died of signal 9

Tags: git

When I try and commit my changes to Github i am prompted with this error message:

```
error: git-seekret died of signal 9
```

I tried uninstalling git but wasn't successful

Comment: @MarcusMüller I remove the duplicated suggestion. thanks

Answer (score 0):

You must have installed https://github.com/apuigsech/git-seekret, and it gets killed (signal 9 is SIGKILL) for some reason.

So, I'd start with removing git-seekret (you probably have put it in a  [*hook*](https://git-scm.com/docs/githooks) in the repo) whilst of course making sure you're not including confidential information in your commits.

Comment: Now I get:git: 'seekret' is not a git command. See 'git --help'.

Comment: did you look into the hooks as I recommended?